# Different types of averages

Tags: computer-science, average

I have a list of words and their frequencies in a text corpus. So there are words like "a", "what", "some" that have really high frequencies, and other like "neurodegenerative" that are less popular.

I want to analyze sentences by assigning to each word its score and then determine if one sentence is more "technical", or more specific to a domain than others. For example:

**"I have a dog and a cat."** vs. **"Mitochondria is the powerhouse of the cell."**

I was thinking of just calculating the average of these frequencies, but sometimes I have a sentence like:

**"Migraine is a serious headache."**, with average 640, and

**"Typical examples of continuous functions which are not holomorphic are complex conjugation and taking the real part."**, with average 600, because of the many short, very common words.

Is there any better way of evaluating such sentences to give a more realistic score, or average, that would indicate how "niche" they are?

Comment: This is very subjective; lots of metrics are available but there's no objective notion that tells us when one is "better" than another.  A simple thing to try would be to just take the max.  Does that work for you?

Comment: @lulu I was thinking of something similar! Like ignoring these very common words and looking only at the ones with a frequency lower than a threshold n, for example. And maybe averaging over these. I was only thinking whether this is computationally more expensive than doing something like I mentioned in the post...

Comment: I don't see a computational problem here, unless you are looking at billions of sentences.  It's just a look up for each word.